# Flutter TextField: multi-line, but don't wrap

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want my textfield to be both multi-line and don't wrap(scroll horizontally).

I can achieve multi-line by setting `maxLines` to `null`, but scrolling horizontally requires `maxLines` to be `1`.

Is there any way I can get both effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ListView

```
 Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
   height: 200.0,
   child: ListView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(
         height: 150,
         width: 1000, // your scroll width
         child: TextFormField(
           controller: controller,
           keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
           scrollPhysics: ScrollPhysics(),
           expands: true,
           maxLines: null,
           decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'hint'),
           validator: (value) {
             if (value.isEmpty) return 'No Blank';
             return null;
           },
         ),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 ),
```

Comment: But it requires you to know the max width of the text ahead of time, plus when you have a really really long text it will still wrap.

Comment: width change to double.maxFinite, enable really really long text

Answer (score 0):

### Your can use `RegExp` to control the `TextField` of `inputFormatters`

(你可以使用正则表达式控制`TextField`的`inputFormatters`属性。)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

TextField(
    maxLines: null,
    minLines: 1,
    inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
            RegExp('[\t\v\n\r\f]+'),
        ),
    ],
),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).